# Does a system of $k$ polynomial equations in $n$ variables always represent an $(n-k)$-dimensional manifold embedded in an $n$-dimensional space?

Tags: systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry

I've noticed a lot of cases in which this rule seems to apply, **provided of course that the polynomial equations are linearly independent** (there wasn't enough space to specify this in the title). And I can't think of any situation where it doesn't work. Is it always true?

Comment: What does *represent* mean precisely here? Do you mean, "Is the common zero set of $k$ polynomials in $\Bbb R[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ linearly independent over $\Bbb R$ always a manifold of dimension $n - k$?"

Comment: If so, this can fail in two ways: (1) The resulting set can simply fail to be an embedded manifold. A standard example is $n = 2$, $k = 1$, $p(x, y) = x^2 - y^2$, whose zero set is a pair of intersecting lines. (2) Given a polynomial $p$ of positive degree, $p$ and $p^2$ have the same zero set but are linearly independent over $\Bbb R$, so if zero set of $p$ is an $(n - 1)$, so is the common zero set of $p$ and $p^2$, so the numerical condition fails.

Comment: @Travis Thank you.
Yes, I meant that by "represent".
I lack a lot of technical concepts here: is there a concept of k-dimensional subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that isn't necessarily a manifold? (e.g. I'd say a pair of intersecting lines is a 1-dimensional object, even though it's not a manifold)
For the second point, that seems the kind of exception that could be pointed out - I just want to know if I'm "on to something" here, and there is some theorem that closely resembles this property I'm talking about...

Comment: Yes, the concept here, i.e., the common zero set of a finite collection of polynomials $p_a \in \Bbb F[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ over a field $\Bbb F$ is an *algebraic variety*---this is the central definition of the field of algebraic geometry (or, arguably, it only used to be). This zero set can also be viewed as the common zero set of the ideal generated by the collection $\{p_a\}$, and there are notions of dimensions of such a set---even when it is not a manifold---and when it is a manifold, this coincides with the usual definition of dimension of a manifold.

Comment: The article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis has some useful background about all this from a computational viewpoint.